# HOW to disable textView selectable gesture recognizer while I need to keep longPress and URL recongise

Tags: ios

I encounter a problem while developing a IM app. In chat view window, the text which user send should not be selected but when the textview is longPressed it should turn out an menuItem providing method dealing with the text context.
My question is how to disable all the gesture recoginzer system provide but keeping longPress, what's more, the URL in textview should be tap and jump into a web page( this means the textView.selected should not be set NO); 
I have a ChatCell Class to create the textview and add into each tableViewCell and my longPress recognizer is added in the instance of each chatCell.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, and workaround as below,

```
(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    WeiboSpecialString *specialString = [self setupSpecialStringRectsWithPoint:point];

    self.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);

    if (specialString.isSpecial) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

this code is suit for myself, 
but try override pointInside, will be fine.